# Rails Checkbox format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am trying to output checkbox with hard coded checkbox value, so far I have coded

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:study_type,['Option1','Option2'], :first, :first)%>
```

The output for checkbox label is first alphabet of respective checkbox. Any way to display full text value label.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways for this:

First, convert your array into an array of arrays like this:

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:study_type, [['Option1'],['Option2']], :first, :first)%>
```

Or, you can use the `:to_s` method like this:

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:study_type, ['Option1','Option2'], :to_s, :to_s)%>
```

Both solutions are "hacky" and I personally wouldn't use it like that. A collection of objects is what's usually used in `collection_check_boxes`. More info [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes).